# c:out and ${} in JSP file

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

is there difference in using

```
<c:out value="${a}"/>
```

and just

```
${a}
```

in a JSP file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, JSTL's `out` tag will transform certain characters to their XML escape sequences [as stated in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html):

> Attribute `escapeXml`: Determines whether characters `<`,`>`,`&`,`'`,`"` in the resulting string should be converted to their corresponding character entity codes. Default value is `true`.

Note that if the goal is to produce cleaner markup then look at the [escapeXml](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function in the `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions` namespace as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For just printing the out put both or same. But when we don't have value for variable 'a' then it will print 'NULL'. 
 To overcome this we can use default in c:out tag.

Ex:`<c: out value='${a}' default='guest' />`

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```